# why is my Gatsby dynamic slug not working

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, slug, contentful

I am going to show the code first and link an [article](https://ibaslogic.com/gatsby-with-contentful-cms/) I am following. Essentially I keep getting this error code "There's not a page or function yet at /episode-one". Can somebody tell me what is wrong with my file path ? I've tried playing around with the folder structure to match the article but nothing has changed.

This is the code for index.js

folder structure -
gatsby-contentful-site\src\episodes/src\episodes\podsode.js
src\pages\EpisodeDetails

index page
{data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.map(slug =>

<Link to={`${slug.node.slug}`}>{slug.node.title}

)}

gatsby node.js

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const response = await graphql(
      `
      query MyQuery {
        contentfulPodcast {
          slug
          title
        }
      }
      
  `)
   response.data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.forEach(edge => {
createPage({
  path: `/EpisodeDetails/${edge.node.slug}`,
  component: path.resolve("./src/episodes/podsode.js"),
  context: {
    slug: edge.node.slug,
  },
})
```

})
}

Episode details

```
function EpisodeDetails ({props}) {
  const data = useStaticQuery 
  (
  graphql `
  query  {
  allContentfulPodcast(sort: {fields: publishedDate, order: DESC}) {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}

  `)
  
    return (
        <div>
     {data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.map(edge => 
     <h2>
                <Link to={`/EpisodeDetails/${edge.node.slug}/`}>{edge.node.title}</Link>
              </h2>
              )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default EpisodeDetails
```

podsode.js

```
export const query = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    contentfulPodcast(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      title
     
      
    }
  }
`

const podsode = props => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{props.data.contentfulPodcast.title}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}


export default podsode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using in the template the query that is supposed to query for all data (episodes) and loop through them to create the dynamic pages and the single query to filter in the `gatsby-config.js`.

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const response = await graphql(
      `
      query MyQuery {
        contentfulPodcast {
          slug
          title
        }
      }
      
  `)
   response.data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.forEach(edge => {
createPage({
  path: `/EpisodeDetails/${edge.node.slug}`,
  component: path.resolve("./src/episodes/podsode.js"),
  context: {
    slug: edge.node.slug,
  },
})
```

In the snippet above you don't have `allContentfulPodcast.edges` to loop through, your node is called `contentfulPodcast`. Test them all in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` but you should do something like:

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const response = await   (
   graphql `
     query  {
      allContentfulPodcast(sort: {fields: publishedDate, order: DESC}) {
        edges {
          node {
           title
           slug
         }
       }
     }
   }
`)
response.data.allContentfulPodcast.edges.forEach(edge => {
  createPage({
    path: `/EpisodeDetails/${edge.node.slug}`,
    component: path.resolve("./src/episodes/podsode.js"),
    context: {
      slug: edge.node.slug,
    },
  })
```

This should create your episodes based on the queried slug (extracted from all episodes and iterated through them) at `localhost:8000//EpisodeDetails/episode-one`

The slug is passed into the template, where you should query the `contentfulPodcast`.

Comment: thank you! this worked!